# App crashes at click with message: 'this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key postReplyButton.'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

My app crashes when I click a cell in my tableView of recent posts. The click is supposed to segue me to the MainTextView which has the postReplyButton. The segue worked until I started experimenting with creating comments for the posts.

Here is the MainTextView code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Firebase

class MainTextView: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var titleText: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var mainText: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var commentPlaceHolder: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var newCommentLabel: UITextView!
var delegate:NewPostVCDelegate?
@IBAction func postReplyButton() {

    // Firebase code here
    let postRef = Database.database().reference().child("posts").childByAutoId()

    let postObject = [
        "comment": newCommentLabel.text,
        "timestamp": [".sv": "timestamp"]
        ] as [String : Any]

    postRef.setValue(postObject, withCompletionBlock: { error, ref in
        if error == nil {
            self.delegate!.didUploadPost(withID: ref.key!)
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }  else {
            // Handle error

            }
        })
    newCommentLabel.text = String()
    commentPlaceHolder.isHidden = false
}
var post: Post?

// MARK: - View Controller LifeCycle

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.setMain()

}
 override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()


newCommentLabel.delegate = self as! UITextViewDelegate


}

private func setMain() {
    guard let post = self.post else {
        return
    }

    titleText.text = post.text
    mainText.text = post.title
}
func textViewDidChange(_commentView: UITextView) {

    commentPlaceHolder.isHidden = !newCommentLabel.text.isEmpty

    }
}
```

For reference, here is my Post class code:

```
import Foundation

class Post {
var id:String
var title: String
var text:String
var createdAt:Date
var comment: [String] = []

init(id: String, title: String,text:String,  timestamp:Double, comment: [String] = []) {
    self.id = id
    self.title = title
    self.text = text
    self.createdAt = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timestamp / 1000)




}
static func parse(_ key:String, data:[String:Any]) -> Post? {
    if let title = data["text"] as? String,
        let text = data["title"] as? String,
        let timestamp = data["timestamp"] as? Double {
        return Post(id: key, title: title,  text: text, timestamp:timestamp, comment: [])
        }


    return nil
}
}
```

I suspect the issue may be with the delegate, which was declared as such in my NewPostViewController:

```
protocol NewPostVCDelegate {
func didUploadPost(withID id:String)
```

}

I have tried troubleshooting the storyboard, but everything seems to be in place. Is there an issue of the reuse of the protocol or perhaps the change of adding comments to the Post class itself? Maybe the issue is that I do not in fact want to upload a new post, but really I just want to add a comment to an existing post. If this is the case, how would I change the delegate or create a new one? I can provide more detail if needed. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Which line your app crash any idea?

Comment: "class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate { " gets the red highlight as the app crashes. This is in the app delegate.  The highlight says "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT"

Comment: Add exception breakpoint so get in Which line app crash MainTextView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually happens if you have an `IBOutlet` that was created previously with the same `postReplyButton` name. To check if your app has any other `Outlet` with the same name go to the `Search` section in your project and search for `postReplyButton` and see if you get multiple results for that name. If you do then click on the one which you don't need and delete it from the properties section.

If you have any `Outlet` which has a bad connection you will see something like this in the properties sections when you click on any one of the search result for `postReplyButton`

[image: Bad connection for <code>IBOutlet</code>]

If that does not work then try renaming the `Outlet` entirely and see if that fixes the problem.

**EDITED:**
For your issue that you mentioned in the comments try this.

Instead of casting your newCommentLabel as an optional type of `UITextViewDelegate` just extend your `viewController` to conform to `UITextViewDelegate`. This should solve the issue.

```
class MainTextView: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
            newCommentLabel.delegate = self
        }
}
```

Once you add `UITextViewDelegate` to your `viewController` you will no longer get the warning in `viewDidLoad` to cast `newCommentLabel` as an optional of type `UITextViewDelegate`.

Comment: Thanks. This problem is fixed. However, (and this may deserve its own thread) commentPlaceHolder is not hidden when I type in the newCommentLabel as I would like it to be.I currently have "newCommentLabel.delegate = self as? UITextViewDelegate". I need the optional or the app won't launch. IWhy can't I just write "newCommentLabel.delegate = self". Also, when I press the reply button the app crashes with "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" around "self.delegate!.didUploadPost(withID: ref.key!)". Let me know if you have any thoughts about this.

Comment: @RyanSchiller i have updated my answer to address this issue as well. Let me know if that helps solve this problem too.

Comment: Nope. The text still stays on top of the text I am writing. Oh! I had to add a space in     "func textViewDidChange(_commentView: UITextView) {
        
            commentPlaceHolder.isHidden = !newCommentLabel.text.isEmpty
        
      }" 
 between " _" and "commentView"... why is that? Maybe I'll make a new thread about my other problem with the delegate causing a crash. (also you have 1 too many brackets in your comment edit) Thanks!

Comment: Oh yeah i added an extra bracket by mistake. I fixed that and I think your `textViewDidChange` method is not getting called. Try deleting it completely and use the compiler to predict the function. Now that you have added the delegate to your viewcontroller the compiler will predict the whole `textViewDidChange` function for you. Maybe some part of it that you typed is not correct. Also add a breakpoint inside `textViewDidChange` to see if it is being called.